# Picture is shown in portrait mode only in ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My orientation is set to landscape and the iphone simulator loads and starts my app in landscape mode. Since ios6 the code above loads the pic in portrait mode instead of landscape mode. Please advise.

**Edit:** the problem starts here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"480x320-background.png"]]];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)anInterfaceOrientation{
    return anInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || anInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: I recommend to use ARC.

Comment: This code snippet looks ok. The error must be somewhere else. Have you set the supportedInterfaceOrientations (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations)?

Comment: I've updated the code. I just found that the problem start before the code I originally posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That what fixed my problem: Under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` 
`[window setRootViewController:headiPhone];`

Answer (score 1):

In iOS6 `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated. You have to use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the autorotate issue in IOS6, perform the following :

Inside `AppDelegate.m` file

Add following

```
if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
{
    // Note : addSubView doesn't work on IOS6
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];
}
else
{
    // For IOS6, use this method
    [window setRootViewController:viewController];
}
```

Instead of

```
[window addSubview: viewController.view];
```

Inside `RootViewController.m` file

// For IOS6, use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` & `shouldAutorotate` instead of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;   
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate 
{
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6, the rotation method is changed. You should implement this method, and return YES.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate 
{
  return YES;
}
```